# How can i dump blob fields from mysql tables

Tags: mysql, blob, dump

i am trying to dump the BLOB fields from mysql table.

but when i dumping blob records using sqlYog am getting unvaluable data.

How can i backup BLOB type fields?

Note:

BLOB field has image.

Answer (score 7):

the parameter **--hex-blob** is useful when you intent to import it to another DB like sqlite.

Comment: The `--binary-as-hex` option is also useful when using mysql rather than mysqldump to export a table.

Answer (score 3):

The official **mysqldump** utility can dump BLOBs fields without any problem, use `-q` or `--opt` when you run the backup.

So for example to backup images_table that contains image in BLOB format :

```
mysqldump --opt -u user -ppass dbname images_table > images.sql
```